# Jest unit test on('error') of createWriteStream

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am using Nestjs and have written the function below which recieves a file from a post request and saves it in a folder in my project.
My issue is I'm not sure how to test the `on('error')` branch.

function to unit test.

```
  saveFile({ createReadStream, filename }: FileUpload): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      createReadStream().pipe(
        createWriteStream(join(process.cwd(), `apps/mull-api/uploads/${filename}`))
          .on('finish', () => resolve(true))
          .on('error', () => {
            console.log(createReadStream);
            reject(false);
          })
      );
    });
  }
```

How I am testing the `on('finish')` branch

```
  it('should save file', async () => {
    const returnedFile = await service.saveFile(mockFile);
    expect(returnedFile).toBe(true);
  });
```

This is what my mockFile looks like. I tried providing a mockFile with empty name and it errors out.

```
export const mockFile: FileUpload = {
  filename: 'zoro',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  createReadStream(): ReadStream {
    return fs.createReadStream(join(process.cwd(), `apps/mull-api/uploads/mock-upload/zoro`));
  },
};
```

Comment: Are you looking for unit testing or integration testing?

Comment: why are you using async function inside promise?

Comment: @slideshowp2 I am trying to unit test this function. I need to meet threshold of 80% coverage in my project

Comment: @SyedMisharNewaz I was following a guide and that's how it was done there
https://stephen-knutter.github.io/2020-02-07-nestjs-graphql-file-upload/

Answer (score 2):

We can mock `createWriteStream`, `.on('finish')` and `.on('error')` methods using `mockImplementation()`. And trigger these two events in the mock implementation function by ourself.

The `'finish'` event `handler` in the mock implementation function is `() => resolve(true)`; The `'error'` event `handler` in the mock implementation function is `() => reject(false);`

See [Mock Implementations](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mock-implementations), and below example:

```
const myMockFn = jest.fn(cb => cb(null, true));

myMockFn((err, val) => console.log(val));
// > true
```

`index.ts`:

```js
import { createWriteStream, ReadStream } from 'fs';
import { join } from 'path';

export interface FileUpload {
  filename: string;
  mimetype: string;
  encoding: string;
  createReadStream(): ReadStream;
}

export class FileService {
  public saveFile({ createReadStream, filename }: FileUpload): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      createReadStream().pipe(
        createWriteStream(join(process.cwd(), `apps/mull-api/uploads/${filename}`))
          .on('finish', () => resolve(true))
          .on('error', () => {
            reject(false);
          }),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { FileService, FileUpload } from './';
import { createWriteStream, WriteStream } from 'fs';
import { mocked } from 'ts-jest/utils';

jest.mock('fs');

describe('64485251', () => {
  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetAllMocks();
    jest.clearAllMocks();
  });
  it('should save file', async () => {
    const mockReadStream = { pipe: jest.fn() };
    const mockFile: FileUpload = {
      filename: 'zoro',
      mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
      encoding: '7bit',
      createReadStream: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(mockReadStream),
    };
    const mockWriteStream = {
      on: jest.fn().mockImplementation(function(this, event, handler) {
        if (event === 'finish') {
          handler();
        }
        return this;
      }),
    };
    mocked(createWriteStream).mockReturnValueOnce((mockWriteStream as unknown) as WriteStream);
    const service = new FileService();
    const actual = await service.saveFile(mockFile);
    expect(mockFile.createReadStream).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockReadStream.pipe).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(createWriteStream).toBeCalledWith(expect.stringContaining('apps/mull-api/uploads/zoro'));
    expect(mockWriteStream.on).toBeCalledWith('finish', expect.any(Function));
    expect(mockWriteStream.on).toBeCalledWith('error', expect.any(Function));
    expect(actual).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should handle error if save file failed', async () => {
    const mockReadStream = { pipe: jest.fn() };
    const mockFile: FileUpload = {
      filename: 'zoro',
      mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
      encoding: '7bit',
      createReadStream: jest.fn().mockReturnValueOnce(mockReadStream),
    };
    const mockWriteStream = {
      on: jest.fn().mockImplementation(function(this, event, handler) {
        if (event === 'error') {
          handler();
        }
        return this;
      }),
    };
    mocked(createWriteStream).mockReturnValueOnce((mockWriteStream as unknown) as WriteStream);
    const service = new FileService();
    await expect(service.saveFile(mockFile)).rejects.toEqual(false);
    expect(mockFile.createReadStream).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockReadStream.pipe).toBeCalledTimes(1);
    expect(createWriteStream).toBeCalledWith(expect.stringContaining('apps/mull-api/uploads/zoro'));
    expect(mockWriteStream.on).toBeCalledWith('finish', expect.any(Function));
    expect(mockWriteStream.on).toBeCalledWith('error', expect.any(Function));
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/64485251/index.test.ts (10.201s)
  64485251
    ✓ should save file (6ms)
    ✓ should handle error if save file failed (3ms)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 index.ts |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        11.344s
```

Comment: Hey I am sorry but I don't understand in your error test case, what is actually triggering the `error` event ?

Comment: @AriaGroult Updated answer with more explaination.